# Logical AND in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have an `if` in my bash script that has to check if EITHER of the 2 files exists, if they don't exist it should echo match.

Code I have:

```
if [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code ]] && [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code.class ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi
```

But this doesn't not seem to work for some reason.

I am 110% sure that these 2 files do not exist. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't enter the `if`.

I am new to bash scripting so I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: I don't think any of the answers posted actually address the question.  What happens when you try the tests individually?  Do `[[ ! -f /etc/.../... ]]; echo $?` for each.

Comment: **A warning**: `[[ -f xxx ]]` returns true if xxx exists **and** is a regular file (or a symlink to a regular file). It will return false if it doesn't exist, or if it can't tell if it exists or not or if it exists but is not a regular file (directory, pipe, device, socket...) or if it's a symlink to a file that doesn't exist or it can't tell if it exists or not or is not a regular file... `[[ -e $file ]] || [[ -L $file ]]` is closer to a test for existence. `ls -d -- "$file" > /dev/null 2>&1` is even closer. And as a rule, this kind of test leads to race conditions. Maybe there's another way.

Comment: I am _way_ late to the party, but my bet is that the `[ -f ]` checks are just failing because they are under `/etc` which you likely do not have the permissions for, and you are running this script as non-root.

Answer (score 18):

If you want **either** then you want `OR`, not `AND`.

```
if [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code ]] || [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code.class ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi
```

- This will match if either or both files are missing.
- Your code will only print `match` if *both* do not exist.

*But*, you said:

> I am 110% sure that these 2 files do not exist. I don't get any errors, it just doesn't enter the if.

So your statement contradicts itself. At least one of those files *must* exist, ***if*** you are running *that* code.

If you want to see how your `if` statement is evaluating, run it with `-x`.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
if [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code ]] && [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code.class ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi
```

Then you'll see the execution.

```
$ ./test.sh
+ [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code ]]
+ [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code.class ]]
+ echo match
match
$
```

Comment: I want it to echo "match" if neither file exists, if one does exist it doesnt print match. I will try it with -x

Comment: In that case your original code should be fine. And indeed it works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't that be like this ? A is a file or B is a file, then blabla.

```
if [[ -f /etc/benchmarking/code ]] || [[ -f /etc/benchmarking/code.class ]]; 
then  
  echo "match"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

This may also work for what you are trying to do. Single brackets are not commonly used today with `bash`, but this is still an option. Using `-o` is effectively an "OR" operation, and `!` negates the condition.

```
var=/etc/benchmarking/code
[ ! -f "$var" -o ! -f "$var.class" ] && echo "match"
```

Comment: The `-o` and `-a` options to `test` and `[` have been deprecated and their use is explicitly discouraged by the POSIX standard (see the "APPLICATION USAGE" section here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your code satisfies your requirements: it will print `match` provided that it can't find either file.

Therefore the reason `match` is not being printed is elsewhere. You should confirm that the code block is being reached, which you can do by surrounding it with a couple of debug message. For example, like this:

```
echo '@ About to enter if...fi block'
if [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code ]] && [[ ! -f /etc/benchmarking/code.class ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi
echo '@ Finished if...fi block'
```

---

My usual preference is for debugging messages to go to *stderr* so as to avoid interrupting the flow of data to *stdout*, but I have avoided that here because you said you were a beginner. Here is one example showing how you could write to *stderr*:

```
echo '@ About to enter if...fi block' >&2
```